# LWC1500 SFDX error retrieving 'Rich Text Area' field using @salesforce/schema

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, richtextarea

I am facing LWC1500: Invalid module id "@salesforce/schema/*sObjectName*.*RichTextAreaField__c*" when deploying through SFDX deploy. Does anybody knows why?

I also tried another Rich Text Area field in the same object and returned me the same error.

Is it there a 'bug' or restriction in SF to retrieve this type of data field using LWC?

LWC Javascript line:

```js
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Case.RichTextDescription__c";
```

Using '<lightning-input-rich-text>' is not an option because I want to generate the value using JS functions, not using HTML.

Comment: Hello Miguel, welcome to SFSE. Could you please share more code of your component (e.g. the `import` line)? It may help others to help you out.